# How does one prevent NaN as return value of various number value calculations?

Tags: javascript, function, numbers, calculation

Im new to Javascript and im trying to do a calculation which changes depending on the number that is typed into the input.
However the functions make the output into a NaN, so Im wondering if I can transform the NaN in a normal number(So that I can add hUeCalc and massCalc together and display it as a number) to use or if I have to use another option to do the calculations.

Maybe switch and case might be an option but im not quite sure if they would have the effect I need.

In the Code below you can see the function which is executed when pressed on a button. Right now when I click the button that activates the function calc I get NaN in tax.innerHTML instead of a number.

Thanks in advance.

```
function calc() {
    let hubraum = Number(hubraumComponent.value);
    let emission = Number(emissionComponent.value);
    let masse = Number(masseComponent.value);

    let hUeCalc = Number(function (){
        if (Diesel.checked == true) {
            ((Math.ceil((hubraum/100)))*9.5)+((emission-95)*2);
        }
        else if (Benzin.checked == true) {
            ((Math.ceil((hubraum/100)))*2)+((emission-95)*2);
        };
    });

    let masseCalc = Number(function (){
        let masseValue;
        if (masse <= 2000) {
           masseValue = (Math.ceil((masse/200)*5.625));
        }
        else if (masse >= 3000) {
            masseValue =(Math.ceil((masse/200)*6.01));
        }
        else if (masse >= 3500) {
            masseValue = (Math.ceil(masse/200)*6.39);
        };
    });
    // let masseValue = (Math.ceil (masse/200));

    let berechnung = (hUeCalc + masseCalc);
    tax.innerHTML = (berechnung) + "€";
    console.log('Calc has been done');
    console.log('hubraum value is ' + hubraum);
    console.log('emission value is ' + emission);
    console.log('masse value is ' + masse);
    console.log('hubraumcalc value is ' + hUeCalc);
    console.log('massecalc value is ' + masseCalc);
}
```

Also here is the HTML incase you want to see the button that activates all of this

```
<div class="input-field-second-calc" onclick="calc()">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="berechnen">
                <br>
                <a id="tax"></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: When it's returning NaN, this mean Not a Number. So no, you can't convert it into a number. But, in most case, this mean  you got a non number value somewhere in your operations. You can try to log the values to see where the problem is exactly

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `Number(function (){`. Could you plealse add the way you call `calc()`?

Comment: `Number.NaN` despite its name of cause is a number value (`typeof Number.NaN` equals `'number'`) one can calculate with. Downside, every calculation result `NaN` was involved in will be `NaN` as well.

Comment: btw which calculation is correct ... talking about nested parentheses ... `(Math.ceil((masse/200)*factor));` vs `(Math.ceil(masse/200)*factor)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you try the following code I think it should work. As you see if you want to use a function to assing a value the function has to return something, if it doesn't there's no value to assign. You also need to make sure the function is excecuted, if you don't the `let hUeCalc = function(){}` just becomes the function identifier.

```
function calc() {
    let hubraum = Number(hubraumComponent.value);
    let emission = Number(emissionComponent.value);
    let masse = Number(masseComponent.value);

    let hUeCalc = Number(function (){
        if (Diesel.checked == true) {
            return ((Math.ceil((hubraum/100)))*9.5)+((emission-95)*2);
        }
        else if (Benzin.checked == true) {
            return ((Math.ceil((hubraum/100)))*2)+((emission-95)*2);
        };
    }());

    let masseCalc = Number(function (){
        let masseValue;
        if (masse <= 2000) {
            return masseValue = (Math.ceil((masse/200)*5.625));
        }
        else if (masse >= 3000) {
            return masseValue =(Math.ceil((masse/200)*6.01));
        }
        else if (masse >= 3500) {
            return masseValue = (Math.ceil(masse/200)*6.39);
        };
    }()); // using () right after the function makes it so it get excecuted immediately
    // let masseValue = (Math.ceil (masse/200));

    let berechnung = (hUeCalc + masseCalc);
    tax.innerHTML = (berechnung) + "€";
    console.log('Calc has been done');
    console.log('hubraum value is ' + hubraum);
    console.log('emission value is ' + emission);
    console.log('masse value is ' + masse);
    console.log('hubraumcalc value is ' + hUeCalc);
    console.log('massecalc value is ' + masseCalc);
}
```

Comment: YES! Thanks is had worked.
Well trying to make the function into a Number was a desperate try to get it to be a number instead of an NaN XD

Comment: It became a NaN because you can't turn a function into a number. also make sure you read the answer below mine on the else if thing.

Comment: I did and changed it too ^^

Comment: @Heroann ... the above code still suffers from the problem of not providing a value for the unmet conditions ... I doubt that it actually will calculate correctly if it comes to edge cases

Comment: @JarneKompier ... the above suggested solution is not even a short lasting patch for it does not tackle the problem of over-complex (error prone, the OP just did proof it with asking for help) and repetitive (5 calculation instead of just 2), thus difficult to read and hard to maintain code.

Comment: @PeterSeliger You're probably right but that wasn't the question asked and I don't think it's necessary to change his code and make it better nor do I think the code I could provide would be considered good information. I'm not going to provide someone with "better" code when I can't guarantee it's actually better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value in your two functions !

When you do :

```
let hUeCalc = Number(function (){
    if (Diesel.checked == true) {
        ((Math.ceil((hubraum/100)))*9.5)+((emission-95)*2);
    }
    else if (Benzin.checked == true) {
        ((Math.ceil((hubraum/100)))*2)+((emission-95)*2);
    };
})
```

You're basically saying please convert the return value of the function to a number and assign it to `hUeCalc`. But as the function return nothing. It is trying to convert undefined to a number. which give NaN as a result.

The same goes for :

```
 let masseCalc = Number(function (){
    let masseValue;
    if (masse <= 2000) {
       masseValue = (Math.ceil((masse/200)*5.625));
    }
    else if (masse >= 3000) {
        masseValue =(Math.ceil((masse/200)*6.01));
    }
    else if (masse >= 3500) {
        masseValue = (Math.ceil(masse/200)*6.39);
    };
});
```

By the way, with :

```
if (masse <= 2000) {
   masseValue = (Math.ceil((masse/200)*5.625));
}
else if (masse >= 3000) {
    masseValue =(Math.ceil((masse/200)*6.01));
}
else if (masse >= 3500) {
    masseValue = (Math.ceil(masse/200)*6.39);
};
```

You'll never get to the last `else if` as if we try it with 3700 for example. It will not match on the first if but on the second as 3700 is greater than 3000. You need to invert the order of the two else if.

And you need to add a else too for the number between 2000 and 3000 (If it's a accepted value)

Comment: Yeah, the else thing makes sense XD Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

A code refactoring should separate both current calculations each into a part that provides/implements a single specialized calculation function and a part which invokes the calculation with the correct values including valid fallback values in case some conditions could not be met.

In addition I suggest to fix the naming. Don't mix the languages. Skip the German part since most of the code (including the logging) is named and commented in English.

```
function getCalculatedHUeValue(displacement, emission, fuelFactor) {
  return (Math.ceil(displacement / 100) * fuelFactor) + ((emission - 95) * 2);
}
function getCalculatedMassValue(mass, massFactor) {
  return Math.ceil(mass / 200 * massFactor);
}

function calc() {
  const displacement = Number(displacementComponent.value);
  const emission = Number(emissionComponent.value);
  const mass = Number(massComponent.value);

  const hUeCalc = getCalculatedHUeValue(displacement, emission,
    (Diesel.checked && 9.5) ||
    (Benzin.checked && 2) ||
    0 // default/fallback value needs to be provided/known.
  );
  const massCalc = getCalculatedMassValue(mass,
  
    ((mass <= 2000) && 5.625) ||
    ((mass >= 3500) && 6.39) ||
    ((mass >= 3000) && 6.01) ||
  
    // what is the factor for the uncovered
    // mass range in between 2001 and 2999?

    0 // this fallback value has to be provided/known.
  );
  const result = (hUeCalc + massCalc);

  tax.innerHTML = (result + "€");

  console.log('Calculation is done');
  console.log('displacement value is ' + displacement);
  console.log('emission value is ' + emission);
  console.log('mass value is ' + mass);
  console.log('hUeCalc value is ' + hUeCalc);
  console.log('massCalc value is ' + massCalc);
}
```

Comment: normaly I only work in english, however this was a privat exercise so to be able to focus on the task I decided to do a few words in german. If I would work on could that is planed for others to be seen than I would never call a function hUeCalc.

Comment: @Heroann ... understood. For me it is more important that the IIFE (your old code as immediately invoked function expression) presented as solution within the currently accepted answer gets refactored into clearly defined tasks (the pure calculation and the conditional part where the arguments are passed into the calculation). Thus it is clear what types one is passing into such a function and what is expected to be returned. More important, with the separated boolean logic it becomes clear that there has to be a final number value to be provided which was entirely missed in the original code.

Comment: @Heroann ... one more thing the conditions of how the mass depended factor gets calculated have to be fixed by switching their precedence. But even then there is a uncovered range in between(including) 2001 and 2999? There needs to be a number value provided as well otherwise the end result for a mass fitting the mentioned range will be `NaN`.